# Handle nested models errors with nested IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, idataerrorinfo

I've one binding that looks like:

```
<MyControl SomeProperty="{Binding VmProperty.SubProperty.SubSubProperty.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Every class on the way implements IDataErrorInfo, but *currently*, only my last class has a real check for the name:

```
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        if (propertyName == nameof(Name))
        {
            if(someCheck){
                return "oh oh";
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public string Error{
    get{
        return this[nameof(Name)];
    }
}
```

Now I'm changing the value to something incorrect, what I get:

1. The `this[string propertyName]` on my last last submodel is called properly and returns an error
2. The `this[string propertyName]` on my view model isn't called(neither are all other level)
3. The control doesn't display the red square around it(it does if I bind directly to a local property of my VM.

So my understanding is that:

1. `IDataErrorInfo` errors are not bubbled up to the Binding
2. My `IDataErrorInfo` implementation of the view model is not called because it doesn't know that a sub-sub-sub-sub-property has been updated.

How should can you handle this? Either a way to be informed when a sub-sub-sub-sub-property is changed(any of the level could be changed, so I registering to every `PropertyChanged` event of every level would be really cumbersome), either bubble up errors?

Answer (score 1):

> So my understanding is that:
>   1. IDataErrorInfo errors are not bubbled up to the Binding

Correct.

> My IDataErrorInfo implementation of the view model is not called because it doesn't know that a sub-sub-sub-sub-property has been updated.

Correct.

> How should can you handle this?

Your child view model needs to notify the parent view model that it has had its state changed and the parent view model needs to handle this event.

In .NET Framework 4.5 and later, there is a new [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.8) interface that declares an `ErrorsChanged` event that you can use for this. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) is an example of how to implement it.

Comment: Funny, I started to implement this, even if it doesn't totally solve my issue. One thing I don't understand: When `GetErrors` is called with null or empty string, shouldn't we return the whole list of error? The docs says it should be the entity-level error ?

Comment: @J4N: The framework calls `GetErrors` for a specific property so this shouldn't be an issue. Why wouldn't implement this interface correctly solve your issue?

Comment: If you check the documentation of the `GetErrors`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.geterrors?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_INotifyDataErrorInfo_GetErrors_System_String_

It says `The name of the property to retrieve validation errors for; or null or Empty, to retrieve entity-level errors.` And I get request from some container(that are default from microsoft or DevExpress) to `GetErrors` with null and empty

Comment: @J4N: So what's your issue?

Comment: When I do returns all errors, then even parent UserControl do have a redbox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967608/how-to-prevent-parent-components-to-displays-errortemplate

Comment: @J4N: How is this related to your original question? And why did you ask a new question without even upvoting this answer?

Comment: It's related to the `GetErrors(null)`, and the proposed implementation of the answers doesn't seems to respeect the microsoft documentation I referenced

Comment: The answer and solution to your original question is to implement another interface. If you have any issues doing this, you should ask a new question and provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example